# Generate pairs from list that hasn't already historically existed

Tags: algorithm, java-stream, pairing

I'm building a pairing system that is supposed to create a pairing between two users and schedule them in a meeting. The selection is based upon a criteria that I am having a hard time figuring out. The criteria is that an earlier match cannot have existed between the pair.

My input is a list of size `n` that contains email addresses. This list is supposed to be split into pairs. The restriction is that this match hasn't occured previously.

So for example, my list would contain a couple of user ids

```
list = {1,5,6,634,533,515,61,53}
```

At the same time i have a database table where the old pairs exist:

```
previous_pairs
---------------------
id     date                    status
1      2016-10-14 12:52:24.214 1
2      2016-10-15 12:52:24.214 2
3      2016-10-16 12:52:24.214 0
4      2016-10-17 12:52:24.214 2

previous_pair_users
---------------------
id     userid
1      1
1      5
2      634
2      553
3      515
3      61
4      53
4      1
```

What would be a good approach to solve this problem? My test solution right now is to pop two random users and checking them for a previous match. If there exists no match, i pop a new random (if possible) and push one of the incorrect users back to the list. If the two people are last they will get matched anyhow. This doesn't sound good to me since i should predict which matches that cannot occur based on my list with already "existing" pairs.

Do you have any idea on how to get me going in regards to building this procedure? **Java 8 streams** looks interesting and might be a way to solve this, but i am very new to that unfortunately.

Comment: So in the example above 1 : 515 is a valid output (and many other pairs are also valid...)?

Comment: So if two users had previous pair, they are more likely to make pair now? or less likely?

Comment: So if the pair has occured previously, it cannot occur again.

Comment: You contradict yourself. You say, that you want to preclude the already existing pairs, but then you say “… *pop two random users and checking them for a previous match. If there exists no match, i pop a new random* ”. Why do you pop a new random, if there is no previous match when not having a previous match ought to be the requirement for a new pairing?

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to create a list with tuples that contain the old matches using group_concat feature of MySQL:

```
SELECT group_concat(MatchProfiles.ProfileId) FROM Matches
INNER JOIN MatchProfiles ON Matches.MatchId = MatchProfiles.MatchId
GROUP BY Matches.MatchId

old_matches = ((42,52),(12,52),(19,52),(10,12))
```

After that I select the candidates and generate a new list of tuples using my pop_random()

```
new_matches = ((42,12),(19,48),(10,36))
```

When both lists are done I look at the intersection to find any duplicates

```
duplicates = list(set(new_matches) & set(old_matches))
```

If we have duplicates we simply run the randomizer again X attemps until I find it impossible.

I know that this is not very effective when having a large set of numbers but my dataset will never be that large so I think it will be good enough.